# Add class on <p> when the phrase is too long

Tags: javascript

I have a long phrase and I need to add a class on it when this phrase fits in one row and a different class when this phrase splits in 2 or 3 rows?

Comment: How do you know whether it fits or not?

Comment: What you are asking for is somewhat tricky because while we humans have the concept of "one/multiple rows of text", the DOM does not. Therefore any possible solution will necessarily have to be a hack that tries to determine "how many rows" from other data.

Answer (score -1):

Well, assuming you already have the `p` node in a variable somewhere:

```
/* assuming p node is in a variable already */
if (p.textContent.length > SOME LENGTH) { p.classList.add("long"); }
```

That depends on how cross browser you need it, but that will work on all modern browsers.

Comment: How exactly is this helpful?